# apt-get can't see the latest version of yasm

Tags: apt-get

I'm trying to build Firefox and I get an error I need a the newest version of yasm, 1.0.1 and I only have 0.8.0.

I did the logical thing:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade yasm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Just to be sure I tried:

```
$ yasm --version
yasm 0.8.0.2194
```

I tried using the Synaptic GUI but it couldn't see any versions besides 0.8.0.

The yasm website says that there is a 1.0.1, how can I make `apt-get` see it?

Comment: Have you tried "sudo apt-get update" ?

Comment: If you are on Lucid, that's the latest version. Upgrade to Maverick or Natty, or find a backport. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yasm

Comment: Try updating ubuntu.